# Where in the kernel init code the static modules are loaded?

Tags: kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

Looking at [init/main.c#start_kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/init/main.c#L531) it's not clear where the statically linked kernel modules are loaded, neither how the kernel gets a list of them.

So, **where are the statically linked kernel modules loaded**?